# Is there a way to check the contents of the latest version of body of a post with SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Based on the bug in tex.stackexchange site described here:

https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7168/27635

I've made this query with SEDE (https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/676480/tex-sx-corruption-based-on-user-id):

```SEDE
declare @UserId int = ##UserId##


select
   Id as [Post Link],
   CreationDate
from posts
where (replace(replace(body,'\\',''), ' ','X')  like '%\XXXX%') 
       and Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
order by CreationDate;
```

which finds the offending lines in posts of a specific user.

However, even after correcting them in the original posts, the query returns the same number of posts.

So, I think that my query searches the original body of the post, instead of the last edited version.

Does anybody know what to change in my query to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) is only updated once a week, on [Sunday](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq).

So you'll have to wait until SEDE is refreshed to see the new results.

If you need up to date results you better use the Stack API, for example [`/search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search)

Comment: I'll wait for tomorrow to see what happens, then... Thanks for your answer.